# Tikz package "external" causes an unclosed tikzpicture@tcb@hooked environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, tikz-external

Unfortunately, I cannot provide a MWE, as after trying for quite some time everything seems to work perfectly with small examples. So this is perhaps some package clash or problem with RTL, I am not sure; would be glad to hear any hint, even for how to set a proper MWE in this case.

I have a long manuscript full with tikz pictures, written in Hebrew (RTL), using XeLaTeX + polyglossia.  My tikz setup is as simple as

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}
```

Since compilation is long, I tried using the external tikz package, by

```
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/]
```

making sure the folder `figures/` really exists.

However, compilation, using

```
xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape "notes".tex
```

now causes an error at the end of the first tikz picture:

```
\begin{tikzpicture@tcb@hooked} on input line 302 ended by \end{tikzpicture}. \end{tikzpicture}
```

The first tikz picture looks as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \shade[ball color=blue] (0,0) circle (.25cm);
  \shade[top color=red,bottom color=black] (0.5,-0.25) rectangle +(0.1,0.5);
  \shade[ball color=blue] (1.1,0) circle (.25cm);
  \shade[ball color=blue] (1.85,0) circle (.25cm);
  \shade[ball color=blue] (2.6,0) circle (.25cm);
  \shade[top color=red,bottom color=black] (3.1,-0.25) rectangle +(0.1,0.5);
  \shade[top color=red,bottom color=black] (3.45,-0.25) rectangle +(0.1,0.5);
  \shade[ball color=blue] (4.05,0) circle (.25cm);
  \shade[ball color=blue] (4.8,0) circle (.25cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Nothing fancy.  But as I said, trying a MWE with this tikzpicture and the same tikz setup, without polyglossia and the rest of the packages I use, works perfect.

Here are some log lines from the log file, until the relevant error:

```
! Package tikz Warning: The key 'up to date check=md5' is impossible, there is 
no macro to compute MD5. Falling back to 'up to date check=diff'.
\openout4 = `figures/notes-figure0.md5'.


===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -halt-on-error -inter
action=batchmode -jobname "figures/notes-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{not
es}\input{notes}"' ========
\openout4 = `notes.auxlock'.

runsystem(pdflatex -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "figures/note
s-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{notes}\input{notes}")...executed.

\openout4 = `notes.auxlock'.

File: figures/notes-figure0.pdf Graphic file (type QTm)
<use  "figures/notes-figure0.pdf" >

! LaTeX Error: \begin{tikzpicture@tcb@hooked} on input line 302 ended by \end{t
ikzpicture}.
```

I guess the problem lies in `tcolorbox`, another package that I use. Indeed, one pdf is processed properly, and my figures folder contain a compiled pdf file which consists of the first tcolorbox in the paper.  The rest of the tcolorboxed are not compiled (it seems), and the `tikzpicture` which generates the error appears in the code after many such tcolorboxes.

Any idea what I should look for, or hints about generating a proper MWE?

Comment: To create a MWE: Start to reduce the document body by removing code in bits from the end (or by moving the \end{document} up), always test inbetween. Then remove code in bits after \begin{document}. The last step ist to reduce the preamble. Don't forget that code is passed through the aux-file, so always compile at least twice. `tikzpicture@tcb@hooked` is a tcolorbox command, so I would look at the parts of the code which use tcolorbox and tikz.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer, it'll probably take me some time. After finding such MWE, I'll post it here as an edit.

Comment: Switch off externalisation for `tcolorbox`es which require it. (Things like `enhanced` etc. cause problems for me. I'm sure there are others.)

Comment: Have you tried to use `\tcbset{shield externalize}` inside the preamble to avoid externalization for `tcolorbox`es?  See Section 4.23 (page 98) of the `tcolorbox` manual.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm, that worked, thanks! Would you like to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the externalization library of `tikz` is used AND externalization is enabled globally AND `tcolorbox` is used with options like `enhanced` from its `skins` library which uses `tikz`, then the externalization process may/will arise a compilation error.

To shield a `tcolorbox` from externalization, use

```
\tcbset{shield externalize}
```

inside your document **preamble**. With it, the drawing part of the `tcolorbox` is not being externalized which is a good thing at the current state of art. Nevertheless, if the tcolorbox contains a tikzpicture,
this picture is still externalized.

Comment: You are a lifesaver. <3